# How to merge two sparse coo matrices from two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy

I have two pandas dataframes df1 and df2 and piece of code that generates me sparse matrix:

```
from scipy import sparse
sparse_matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((df['r'].astype('category').cat.codes, \
               (df['u'].astype('category').cat.codes, \
                df['i'].astype('category').cat.codes)))
```

where `df['r']` is int, but `df['u']` and `df['i']` are strings, this is why I have

```
astype('category').cat.codes
```

Dataframes `df1` and `df2` are two big to combine them (I have memory error).

The idea is to generate `sparse_matrix_df1` and `sparse_matrix_df2` separately and then combine that. The problem is `df['u']` and `df['i']` sometimes has the same values in df1 and df2, in that case `df['r']` should be summed up, so I cannot simply merge `sparse_matrix_df1` and `sparse_matrix_df2`.

How to get sparse_matrix and keep proper keys? Perhaps one can think about the problem as adding df to sparse-matrix in batch-style, so to speak.

Comment: What's supposed to happen with duplicate points?

Comment: Good eye, somehow I removed part of the sentence - corrected, thank you. 
So in case of duplicate points (so 'u' and 'i' are the same) the `df['r']` should be added together.

Comment: The default action for `coo` is to add duplicates.  So just put all the `data`, `row`, `col` values in their respective 3 arrays, and let `coo_matrix` do the 'merge'.  Actually `coo` keeps the values separate; the merging is done on display or conversion to `csr` for calculations.